# How to fix Key error - "Groups" in using Fousquare API @ Python?

Tags: python-3.x, foursquare

I am trying to list nearby venues using get Nearby venues that are previously defined, and every line worked fine and then I cannot label properly nearby venues using Foursquare although its working fine ( I have to reset my Id and Secret as it just stop working). Im using Python 3.5 at Jupyter Notebook

What Im doing wrong? Thank you!!

```
 BT_venues=getNearbyVenues(names=BT_df['Sector'],
                            latitudes=BT_df['Latitude'],
                             longitudes=BT_df['Longitude']
                              )

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  ----
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
 <ipython-input-99-563e09cdcab5> in <module>()
  1 BT_venues=getNearbyVenues(names=BT_df['Sector'],
  2                           latitudes=BT_df['Latitude'],
   ----> 3                           longitudes=BT_df['Longitude']
  4                                   )

<ipython-input-93-cfc09962ae0b> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, 
 longitudes, radius)
 18 
  19         # make the GET request
   ---> 20         results = requests.get(url).json()['response'] 
['groups'][0] 
 ['items']
 21 
 22         # return only relevant information for each nearby venue

KeyError: 'groups'


  As for groups this was the code

  venues = res['response']['groups'][0]['items']

  nearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON

   # columns only
   filtered_columns = ['venue.name', 'venue.categories', 
   'venue.location.lat', 'venue.location.lng']
   nearby_venues =nearby_venues.loc[:, filtered_columns]

   # only one category per a row
   nearby_venues['venue.categories'] = 
   nearby_venues.apply(get_category_type, 
   axis=1)

   # columns cleaning up
   nearby_venues.columns = [col.split(".")[-1] for col in 
   nearby_venues.columns]

   nearby_venues.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check response['meta'], you may have exceeded your quota.

Answer (score -2):

If you need an instant resolution, create a new foursquare account. Then create new application and use your new client id and secret to call api

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Please note that this response is better suited as a comment. On the OP's post. While it may be useful, it is not considered a full and proper Answer to the OP's question, according to SO guidelines. Once you get a little reputation, you'll be able to comment on posts.